# What is the difference between Google Apps Script add-on and web app?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-add-on

The issue is mainly that I don't understand what is meant by the web app. I understood that it must support HTTP requests, but otherwise is it the same? Or is the difference in publishing?

I looked on documentation: 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web. But I still do not understand the difference.

First, I thought that web app has its own UI and it mustn't be connected with the G Suite environment, but the documentation says:

> Both standalone scripts and scripts bound to G Suite applications can
>   be turned into web apps…

My thought wouldn't make sense for a bound script. Or would it?
What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Google Apps Script web app will have it's own URL to be used to make HTTP GET/POST requests.

A G Suite Add-on adds a menu to a G Suite app (Google Docs, Google Forms, Google Sheets, Google Slides)

A Google Apps Script project could be bounded or standalone and could be used to post a G Suite add-on, a web app or both.